# How to change model value of spring when popup close

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I have a page with submit button.If user's not click checkbox,show popup error message.If user click checkbox,go to success page.My problem is "popup error show while i click browser back arrow from success page".

But firefox back arrow click not show popup.

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("sample")    
public RedirectView agree(User user,Model model,RedirectAttributes ra) {    

    if(null == user.getContent() || user.getContent().isEmpty()) {
        ra.addFlashAttribute("message", "user not click");
        ra.addFlashAttribute("user", user);

        return new RedirectView("checkagree");
    }

    return new RedirectView("success");
}
```

js:

```
function productMethod() {

    var check =document.getElementById("checkbox").checked;

        if(check) {
            $("#content").prop('value', "agree");

        } else {

        $("#content").prop('value', "");
    }
}

function agreeCheck() {

    var check =document.getElementById("checkbox").checked;

    if(check) {
        $("#checkbox").prop("checked", true);
    }  else {
        $("#checkbox").prop("checked", false);
    }
}

var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

$(document).ready(function() {

    var self = $('.clearable');
    var arrLen = self.length;
    for(var len = 0; len < arrLen; len++) {
        if(self[len].value) {
            $(self[len]).addClass('x onX');
        }       
    }

    if(modal) {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }
});

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

if(modal) {
    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}

window.onclick = function(event) {

    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Is this related to Spring or about browser compatibility?